# Using velocity/time data to create a displacement/acceleration matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I've recently started a new job and having never used MATLAB before, I'm a little stuck. Any help would be much appreciated.
Here is the story. I have been given the velocities of fragmentation pellets at time intervals of 0.001 milliseconds. There are 28 gauges (i.e 28 sets of data) and each gauge has 20,000 readings. I have created a matrix consisting of all this data. 
My objective to take that matrix and create 2 more matrices with the corresponding displacement and acceleration values of each reading. The next step is to export the time and acceleration values to an excel spreadsheet. 
I am at a loss as to how to do this. I have tried to integrate and differentiate but I cant seem to get it right. Is it possible to create a function that takes the velocity data and automatically calculates acceleration/displacement? (This would make things easier as people in the future could use that same code) 
Any help on how to solve any part of this problem would be much appreciated. I've only been using the software 3 days.

Many thanks.

Comment: Well displacement is simply the integral of velocity, so that would be `cumsum * dt`. Acceleration is the derivative of velocity so that would be `diff / dt` (for the forward difference estimate of the derivative)

Comment: Thank you. I'm on my way in now so I'll try ASAP.

Comment: Exporting to Excel is straightforward with `xlswrite`.

Comment: While calculating your derivation did you multiply with your timestep (here 0.001ms)? I would go like `deriv_mat = diff(velocity_mat) * timestep;`

Comment: yes I multiplied by my timestep. I actually converted it into seconds for ease later on. I have successfully created a displacement and acceleration matrix, and exported to excel. Thanks for all your help.